# forward declaration in another file c++

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Is it legal to forward declare in another header's file? For example:

```
#ifndef _MAIN_H_
#define _MAIN_H_
class ClassA;
class ClassB;
#include "classa.h"
#include "classb.h"
#endif

#ifndef _CLASSA_H_
#define _CLASSA_H_
#include "main.h"
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB b;
};
#endif

#ifndef _CLASSB_H_
#define _CLASSB_H_
#include "main.h"
class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassA a;
};
#endif
```

Both class A and class B depend on each other, and both have an object of the other type. What I did was forward declared both classes in another file. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: You need to break the cycle. Try thinking about what would happen if you attempted to create an instance of A. (Create A, need to create a B, need to create an A for that, need to create a B for that, ...)

Comment: That's coupling. Isn't it? Why do you need each other's definition? Concrete examples? Can you make them into subclasses if their functionality are so similar?

Comment: @CppLearner "Why do you need each other's definition?" my mistake

Comment: While it's bad, but utlimately that's a design problem. So you should actually provide the actual name of the two classes and what they do. From there we can help figuring out the best design practice.

Comment: You need to (or rather, should) use pointers for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is legal to forward-declare classes across headers.

However, in your example, you are instantiating both classes in each other, which is absolutely illegal!

To show the reasoning behind this, think about the following:

Let `ClassA` take 1 byte without `b` and `ClassB` also 1 byte without `a`.
Now, include `b`: `ClassA` now takes 2 byte. Now include `a`: `ClassB` now takes 3 bytes. Now we have to update the size of `ClassA` to 4 bytes due to the size increase of `ClassB`. Following that logic `ClassB` is now 5 bytes, `ClassA` 6 bytes, `ClassB` 7  bytes.......

To deal with this, you probably would like to change the type of (at least) one of `a` and `b` to a pointer or reference to the respective class. When doing this (in c/c++), make sure you understand your memory management!

The solution to your original problem could then look as follows:

ClassA.h

```
#pragma once
class ClassB;
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB* b;
}
```

ClassB.h

```
#pragma once
#include "ClassA.h"
class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassA a;
}
```

Note that ClassB.h requires ClassA.h since for demonstration purposes: `ClassB` contains a full object of type `ClassA`, so the definition of `ClassA` is required!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But then you should use  `ClassA* a;` or `ClassA& a;` instead of `ClassA a;` (with corresponding initialisation in cpp file)
Because there is no information about size of `ClassA` to calculate size of `ClassB`.